# confidence interval in terms of the empirical CDF

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Recall that the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of X is defined as:

$F(x)=P(w: X(w) \leq x)$

Using the sequence $(X_i)$ estimate the CDF F(x) using the empirical CDF:
$$
\bar{F_n}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{(-\infty, x)} (X_i).
$$
For each fixed $x \in \mathbb {R}$, show that
$$
\mathbb {I}_{\alpha, n}(x)
 = \left\{  y \in \mathbb {R}: \bar{F_n}(x)- \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \leq y \leq \bar{F_n}(x) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \right\}
$$

is a $(1-\alpha) \times 100$% confidence interval for F(x) in the sense that

$P(w: F(x) \in \mathbb {I}_{\alpha, n}(x) \geq 1-\alpha)$

How to prove this statement?

My attempt: I can convert the $$
\mathbb {I}_{\alpha, n}(x)
 = \left\{  y \in \mathbb {R}: \bar{F_n}(x)- \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \leq y \leq \bar{F_n}(x) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \right\}
$$ to

$$
\mathbb {I}_{\alpha, n}(x)
 = \left\{ ny- \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2 \sqrt{ \alpha}} \leq n\bar{F_n}(x) \leq ny+ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2 \sqrt{ \alpha}}  \right\}
$$

Then how to do next?

Comment: Assuming $X_i$ are iid, $n \overline{F}_n(x)$ is Binomial($n,F(x)$) distributed, so this amounts to a concentration inequality for the binomial distribution.

Comment: @Ian Do I need to use central limit theorem?

Comment: No, the central limit theorem won't actually solve this problem for finite $n$. You need some other concentration inequality. You can check whether Chebyshev's inequality is good enough for this task, if not then you'll need something more specialized for the binomial distribution.

Comment: I didn't get the proof. I attempt something in my edit. Can you tell mw how to do the next?

Comment: As Ian suggests, you indeed are intended to use the Chebyshev inequality. You can start by computing the mean and variance of $\overline{F}_n(x)$.

Comment: You also have a typo on a placement of parentheses, the confidence interval is in the sense that for a given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $P[F(x) \in \mathbb{I}_{\alpha, n}(x)]\geq 1-\alpha$.  So $F(x)$ is a fixed (nonrandom) number here, while $\mathbb{I}_{\alpha, n}(x)$ is an interval with random left and right endpoints.

Comment: @Michael The mean of $\bar{F_n} (x)$ is F(x), the variance of $\bar{F_n} (x)$ is F(x)(1-F(x))/n. Then what next?

Comment: I agree. You can call the mean $p$ and the variance $p(1-p)/n$ if you like. Can you apply the Chebyshev bound? You want to bound $P[|\overline{F}_n(x)-F(x)|\geq c]$. [Edit: I accidentally wrote "Can you apply the Chernov bound" when it should have been "Chebyshev bound."  You can use Chernov-Hoeffding for a tighter bound for certain values of $\alpha$, but you want Chebyshev here.]

Comment: @Michael I am stuck at this step. I don't know how to use Chebychev's inequality here. I can write down $P(|\bar{F_n} (x)- p|) \geq a) \leq p(1-p)/an$

Comment: Can you state the Chebyshev inequality? Say, for a general random variable $Y$ with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: For any random variable X, $P(|X-E(X)| \geq a) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$

Comment: Okay so now you just need to translate: What is $X$ in your case, and what is $E[X]$?  [You may want to use $c$ in your statement of Chebyshev, instead of $a$, since $a$  looks too much like the already used $\alpha$.]

Comment: but how to choose a? I mean a in my Chebyshev inequality formula.

Comment: Eventually you will choose that threshold (call it either $a$ or $c$) to ensure your upper bound is equal to the desired value $\alpha$.  But you first need to get that upper bound.

Comment: Yes, I understand your logic. But I don't know how to connect our discussion here to the original interval that I am showing to prove. Our original given interval even doesn't include $F(x)$, or p.

Comment: You do not need to do that yet, but eventually you will use $$\{|X-E[X]|\leq c\} \iff \{X-c\leq E[X]\leq X+c\} \iff E[X] \in [X-c, X+c]$$ This should help you decide what to use for $X$, $E[X]$, and $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb P (F(x) \in \mathbb I_{\alpha,n}) = \mathbb P \left(F(x) \in \left\{  y \in \mathbb {R}: \bar{F_n}(x)- \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \leq y \leq \bar{F_n}(x) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \right\}\right) = \mathbb P\left (\bar{F_n}(x)- \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \leq F(x) \leq \bar{F_n}(x) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \right) = 
\mathbb P\left (|\bar{F_n}(x) - F(x) | \leq \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \right) =
\mathbb P\left (|\bar{F_n}(x) - \mathbb E\left[\bar{F_n}(x)\right] | \leq \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n \alpha}} \right) $$

Now, the variance of $\bar{F_n}(x)$ is at most $0.25/n$ since it is a binomial with $n$ samples (this is true for any binomial of $n$ samples, can you figure out why?). So by Chebychev:

$$\geq 1-\frac{0.25/n}{1/(2\sqrt{n\alpha})^2} = 1-\alpha$$

Answer (score 2):

This problem wants you to use an exact bound that holds for all $n$, such as the Chebyshev inequality or the Chernov-Hoeffding inequality, rather than a central limit theorem approximation. As a comment by Ian suggests, this problem can be solved by using the Chebyshev inequality alone.  It turns out that the Chernov-Hoeffding inequality will give you a tighter bound for values of $\alpha$ that are small enough, but that is not needed in this problem.

As you have already noted in comments, the Chebyshev inequality for a general random variable $X$ with mean $E[X]$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is
$$ P[|X-E[X]|\geq c] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$$
You can choose the parameter $c$ to make the upper bound $\sigma^2/c^2$ as desired. Also recall that
$$ \{|X-E[X]|\leq c\} \iff X-c \leq E[X]\leq X+c \iff E[X] \in [X-c, X+c]$$

In comments, you have already computed the means and variances you need for this problem so you are almost done.  I will only add that the upper bound $\sigma^2/c^2$ may depend on a certain parameter $p \in [0,1]$, so you can make the bound true regardless of that parameter by maximizing the bound over all $p \in [0,1]$.